# How to set the height of a GridView to be of minimum size?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a **GridView** and a **Text** inside a **Column**.

The **GridView** is defined with a **SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount** where the **crossAxisCount** is 3 and the number of children is 6.

The only reason the **GridView** is being expanded is to prevent a rendering error due to the existence of unbounded height.

A visual structure would look as follows:

```
Scaffold:
  Column:
    Expanded:
      GridView:
         Contianer()
         Contianer()
         ...

    Text()
```

The expanded **GridView** is pushing the **Text** to the bottom of the screen and this is not the intended behavior. Instead, the height of the **GridView** should shrink as much as possible similar to the effect of a **Column** when **mainAxisSize** is set to minimum.

Comment: You can use Column(Row(3widget)+Row(..)) for 6 item

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I don't like the idea of simulating a GridView with columns and rows. There must be another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `shrinkWrap: true`. Also just for 6 items Column/Row can be use.

```dart
GridView.count(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  crossAxisCount: 3,
),
```

You can check more about [shrinkWrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html), not recommended for long list.